# Intersection number on $S^k$

Tags: differential-topology

Is the intersection number on $S^k$ is always zero? Choose $X$ a compact submanifold of $S^k$, and $Z$ a closed submanifold of complementary dimension, viewing $I_2(X,Z) = I_2(i, Z)$ where $i: X \hookrightarrow Y$ is the inclusion. Then $X,Z$ can always be homotopped to be disjoint?

Comment: No, the intersections aren't always zero.  For example, you can choose $Z$ to be zero dimensional  and $X=S^k$.

Comment: Thank you Ryan - how about when $X,Z$ are not finite set? Is the reason stands? Thanks @RyanBudney

Comment: Yes, if they're manifolds of dimension strictly between $0$ and $k$ then for example studiousus's answer applies.  You could also argue the two manifolds can be *isotoped* to be disjoint, because the sphere is the one-point compactification of Euclidean space, which is contractible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, intersection number is zero unless either X or Z is a finite set. This follows from vanishing of homology groups of the sphere except in dimension 0 and k. You can also homotope the submanifolds to be disjoint. Hint: first do this for $R^k$ instead of the sphere.

Comment: Dear studiousus - thank you very much. Is my claim right, though? Thank you!

Comment: Yes, that's what I said in my answer: True if $dim(X) dim(Z)\ne 0$, false if $dim(X)dim(Z)=0$.